# How to know when visibleViewController changes(Push and Model both)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, runtime

I am developing a library in iOS which tracks changes in VisibleViewController of any iOS application. My **aim is to subclass next VisibleViewController's viewDidLoad**. 
Currently I am tracking it via viewWillDisappear in current viewController and then getting reference of next VisibleViewController using:

```
UIViewController * nextViewController =  [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] visibleViewController];
```

But this approach doesn't work as when current viewController's viewWillDisappear gets called nextViewController's viewDidLoad finished already.

Is there any different approach to get reference of next visibleViewController?  when it is initialised, if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
[self.navigationController topViewController];
```

Comment: I would like to know some kind of delegate or approach which tells when to look for nextViewController.